# Prevent JQuery from firing multiple AJAX GET Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function

```
 function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7) {
         //$(window).unbind('scroll');

         jQuery.get('moreProfileComments', function (e, success) {
             $(window).scroll(scrollEvent);
             console.log(e);
             var result_div = $(e).find('#user_comments #u_cont div');
             var original_div = $('#user_comments #u_cont div');

             if (result_div.last().html() === original_div.last().html()) {
                 //alert("TEST");
                 //$(window).unbind('scroll');
             } else {
                 //$(rs).appendTo('#search_results').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#user_comments #u_cont').append($(e).find('#user_comments #u_cont').html());
                 $(window).scroll(scrollEvent);
             }
         }, "html");

     }
 };
```

that makes an ajax request, how do I make sure it would only fire 1 ajax request? if a request has been already or sent. I do not want multiple ajax request.

Comment: Sending Ajax request on scroll event is a terrible idea.

Comment: I am making a continuos scroll pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good idea to use throttled versions of event handlers for `resize` and `scroll` events. But to address your specific problem with making multiple request you can use the following code.

```
 var requestIsRunning; //Flag to indicate that there is a pending request.

 function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7) {

         //do nothing if there is an active moreProfileComments request;
         if(ruquestIsRunning) {return;};

         requestIsRunning = 1;
         jQuery.get('moreProfileComments', function (e, success) {
             $(window).scroll(scrollEvent);
             console.log(e);
             var result_div = $(e).find('#user_comments #u_cont div');
             var original_div = $('#user_comments #u_cont div');

             if (result_div.last().html() === original_div.last().html()) {
                 //alert("TEST");
                 //$(window).unbind('scroll');
             } else {
                 //$(rs).appendTo('#search_results').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#user_comments #u_cont').append($(e).find('#user_comments #u_cont').html());
                 $(window).scroll(scrollEvent);
             }
         }, "html")
         //when request is complete restore the flag
         .always(function(){ 
              requestIsRunning = 0;
          });

     }
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

`scroll` event like the `resize` event fires hundred times(*depends on the browser*), you should use a plugin that provides a `throttle` method like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or you can use `setTimeout` function.

An underscore.js `throttle` example:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(scrollEvent, 500);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```

An example using `setTimeout` function:

```
var timeout = '';
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       // Do something here
    }, 300); 
})
```

A related article by John Resig:
http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/